# Passing data using $.ajax to PHP leaves $_POST empty

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So I'm making a Wordpress site and want to send data (css styles dynamically created by jQuery) to PHP. The reason for this (not fully relevant to this question) is to write the data as a .css file that is loaded at the beginning of every page--making it so there's no visible 'change' of styles when js executes (well, only the first time the page is loaded). I'm sure there's probably a better way to do this.

But back to the main part (sending data from jQuery to a .php). I'm executing a js script (on "front-page.php") that does this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    $(window).on("load", function() { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "create-style.php",
            data: { style : styleString }, 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function () {
                console.log("success");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The console says 'success', so I assume data is getting passed to create-style.php.

`create-style.php`'s write function does this

```
 $file = 'new-style.css';
 $style = $_POST['style'];
 file_put_contents($file, $style, LOCK_EX);
```

Now the first thing I tried was having the function included in Wordpress's functions.php. I don't know a lot about Wordpress or web development in general, but it seems intuitive that this wouldn't work since probably the php files get executed before the js (so how could it get the data?)

In an attempt to solve this I rewrite the `create-style.php` as a cron using `wp_schedule_single_event` to fire when someone visits the site, with a slight delay:

```
add_action('write_style_cron', function(){
    // the above writing function
});

wp_schedule_single_event(time() + 10, 'write_style_cron'); // give it a slight delay to make sure jQuery happens
```

However, no $_POST data gets written to the file and doing any tests shows it's empty. I've done a lot of tests and know that:

- cron functionality is basically working
- - the writing function works with test values
- $_POST is showing as completely empty and I get an "Undefined index" error in the `/wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron`
- $.ajax is firing `success`
- there are no other php / js errors

Thanks for reading this very long post. Been searching the internet all day for solutions and decided it might be best to just ask. I'd much appreciate any ideas.

Comment: Did you check if the `styleString` is passing a value?

Comment: Check your browser's *Network* console... do you see the POST request? If so, check the request data and the response. Is the response completely empty?

Comment: Also, why are you wrapping a window *load* event handler inside the document *ready* handler? Seems redundant

Comment: @Phil thanks for the tip looking at the Network console. In its entry for `create-style.php`, the response is a "Fatal error:  Call to undefined function add_action()`. Maybe that's it, eh? (btw can't recall exactly why I put it in window load) edit: aha maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15670004/wordpress-call-to-plugin-php-file-via-ajax?rq=1) would help. Guess I didn't search stackoverflow enough.

Answer (score -1):

Try using this code:

```
jQuery(function(){
$('#yourFormName').on('submit', function (e) { //on submit function
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'post', //method POST
      url: 'create-style.php', //URL of page where to pass values
      data: $('#yourFormName').serialize(), //seriallize is passing all inputs values of form
      success: function(){ 
              console.log("success");
                  },
    });
}
});
```